# Register tlb COM

Tags: c#, dll, com, regasm, tlbimp

I made a COM Wrapper for c# to use it in vba. I compiled it, after with gacutil and regasm I installed it on my pc, after I refered it in vba and it worked perfectly.

Now I want to use this foo.tlb in another PC, but it doesn't have gacutil or VS.

I just have to execute regasm.exe for this tlb? Or what else I need to do it?

Comment: COM components should have an installer.  Most programmers equate creating one to having a root-canal done.  But simple with the right utility, like this [VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d).  You don't *have* to have one, you can limp along with Regasm.exe without putting it in the GAC.  Use the /tlb and /codebase options.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use `regasm` on the *assembly* as Hans suggested:

Put the assembly somewhere on the target system and call `regasm /tlb /codebase <assembly name>`. This will create a new `*.tlb` file and the necessary registry entries to make the assembly and type library COM visible in their current location.

Without the `/codebase` the assembly needs to be in the GAC to be found.